# ToolBar Spinner Odd Behavior

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

I am using a ToolBar Spinner to switch among the 6 activities of my App. The opening activity, which I call MainView, has only the spinner [plus a help link on the ToolBar action menu]. The user selects from the spinner which of the other 5 activities he wishes to run and when finished uses the ToolBar back button of that activity to return to MainView.

It all works fine except, after returning to MainView from any of the other activities, the name of that activity remains displayed in the Spinner, not MainView as i had expected. Plus, if user wants to return to that same activity he must select any of the others first.

I had thought that when the App returns to MainView using the ToolBar back button it would do so by calling the MainView OnCreate, and the MainView spinner would be recreated thus displaying MainView. But this appears to be not the case.

I have tried a few things including setSelection(0) in onCreate, re-initializing the spinner in onStart and onResume - but none has made a difference. Hope you can help.

xml for spinner ...

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

initialization code for spinner

```
    String[] mainview_names = new String[]
        {"MainView", "WebView", "JsoupView", "CodeView", "Connectivity", "FtpView"};
    Spinner mainSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_main);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>
        (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mainview_names);
    mainSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mainSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    //        mainSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

The Listener ...

```
public class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            switch (pos){
                case 0:                 // Main View
                    break;
                case 1:                 // Web View
                    BrowseWWW();
                    break;
                case 2:                 // Jsoup View
                    LoadHTMLJsoup();
                    break;
                case 3:                 // Code View
                    LoadHTMLCode();
                    break;
                case 4:                 // Connectivity
                    GetHTMLConn();
                    break;
                case 5:                 // Ftp View
                    GetHTMLFtp();
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Additional information:

The 5 activities each respond to the back button with code structured like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        help.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case android.R.id.home:     // up navigation
                finish();
            return true;

            case R.id.load:
        //  ....
                }
            return true;

            case R.id.Clear
        //  ...
            return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

@Override
    public void finish() {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("urlKey", url.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("tokenKey", token.getText().toString());
        i.putExtra("redirectsKey", HttpURLConnection.getFollowRedirects());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        super.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using different activities for all that, or just one activity with 6 fragments? Also, it may help if you show what `BrowseWWW()` and other methods do.

Comment: No fragments. 6 activities, one main and 5 started one at a time from the ToolBar Spinner. Note that it runs on the Genymotion and on 4 or 5 devices on the Samsung Remote Test Lab. It just does not run on my local 4 mini. And regardless if i do anything with the activity, just hit the back button and it misbehaves. So i think what the activities do is not relevant to what is going on. The last line of the LogCat may be a hint to the problem.

Comment: I apologize, I thought I had mentioned this in the post originally, that  it runs on the Genymotion and on 4 or 5 devices on the Samsung Remote Test Lab. It just does not run on my local 4 mini. I must have accidentally edited it out as it is in my rough copy :(

Comment: Err... so which is your problem, does it crash or is the problem that your spinner state is inconsistent? :) the error log suggests there might be some shortcoming of WebView version on the S4, you should take a look at the android version S4 mini is running.

Comment: Once again i must apologize. I am having two different problems with this app. I have been keeping them separate in my mind with the intention of posting two questions. Now i have parts of both here in this one question. The original question i posted is the issue i wish to discuss in this thread. The LogCat belongs to the other problem. I will edit/delete it from this post and start a new question for that other problem.

To answer your question directly, the problem is that the spinner state is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the spinner state issue:

Without digging into more of your code, here's my theory:

You're in activity `A`. You select something in the spinner, say `B`. Now you're in activity `B` and activity `A` is paused retaining state it had -- i.e. it has the item corresponding to `B` selected in the spinner. When you go back from `B`, activity `A` is resumed in that exact state and, of course, still has the `B` item in the spinner. You can't go to `B` again right away, because if you re-select `B`, your select handler will not be called (since there's no change).

The fact that `Activity` is not destroyed every time is probably what tricked you, that's why you should take a look at google [guide on Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) -- it will probably save you a lot of guessing time :)

So, to fix your issue with spinners, you should override the `onResume()` method of each activity and use it to set the spinner to the state corresponding to that activity -- that's the short version.

Long version is, *you're probably going somewhat against the flow* using toolbar spinner to navigate between activities.

Navigation can be faster and more intuitive you implement your Web, Jsoup, Code and other top-level views as [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (also, [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)) inside a single `Activity`, that's exactly what they're for. It'll probably be more user-friendly to use [Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html#tabs) instead of `Spinner`.